# HTML form post to asp.net controller across domains

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, post, cross-domain

I've created an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application that must receive a post from an external site (within the same corporate intranet).  I've set up my controller method and created another web application to simulate the post.  The posting page form looks like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:12345/Home/MethodName" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="fullName" value="Joseph B. Blow" />
    <input type="text" id="dateOfBirth" value="3/4/1977" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I start my "receiver" app in debug mode and set a break point on the first line in "/Home/MethodName" and the breakpoint is hit.  `MethodName` looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult MethodName()
{
    ...code here
}
```

When I check the `Request.Form` object in `MethodName`, it's completely empty.  Using developer tools in the browser the Content-Length is 0.  I've tried creating a custom model class that has the properties `fullName` and `dateOfBirth` and using that as the sole parameter in `MethodName` but the properties of the object are always null.  I also tried to use the `FormCollection` object, it contained no keys.  Another attempt I made was to use a `StreamReader` object and use it on the `Request.InputStream` object to see if that would pull the posted values in.

I might consider using an ajax call to post the data but the issue with that is the user must also be redirected to the page.  There is a company security policy against not using the querystring to pass data from site-to-site (I know, a post isn't necessarily more secure than a get, but dems the rules).

This doesn't seem like it should be this hard but I'm having a bear of a time with it.  If anyone has done something similar or could point me in another direction to get these values passed from one page to another, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you doing this in MVC instead of using a webAPI project to handle the receiving request?

Comment: Initially this was a quick and dirty app.  I was achieving the result by using the querystring.  Since it's blow up a bit and I found out about the "no querystring" rule.  Is it not possible to do this without Web API?

Comment: Yeah probably, but my gut reaction would be to build out a quick api that functions as my "handler" so to speak and then go from there

Comment: I'm a big dummy.  All I had to do to get it to work was to include the name attribute in the form inputs, then the controller could see the values.  In other words instead of <input type="text" id="fullName" value="Joseph B. Blow" /> I changed it to <input type="text" NAME="fullName" value="Joseph B. Blow" />.  Only reason I'm exposing myself as a complete tool is in hopes that it will help someone else that may be having the same issue.

Comment: you could post this as answer, might be more helpful than a comment

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big dummy. All I had to do to get it to work was to include the name attribute in the form inputs, then the controller could see the values. In other words instead of

```
<input type="text" id="fullName" value="Joseph B. Blow" />
```

I changed it to

```
<input type="text" NAME="fullName" value="Joseph B. Blow" />
```

Only reason I'm exposing myself as a complete tool is in hopes that it will help someone else that may be having the same issue.